# Flagging content via email notification using Rules, Flags and Drupal 7

Tags: 7, rules, flags

I'm using the [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) module to allow authors to approve (or flag) certain types of content that anonymous users upload.

Everything is working well, but I would like to extend the approval feature so it can be done using a notification email as well.  I can trigger an email without issue using the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module, but I would like to embed the non-ajax version of the flag link to simplify the approval process.

Is it possible to retrieve and send a 'flag' link via email using only the Flag and Rules module?  Otherwise, what would be the best way to go about allowing users to flag content via automated notification emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the Flags module in Drupal 7 has full Rules support since several months, but only in the -dev version, so have you tried something never than the beta?

This ought to be enough to accomplish what you ask for, but I may misunderstand where you are having problems with the integration.

Comment: This was exactly what I was hoping for. I see that they have added native support for flags with tokens like [node:flag-*something*].  Way cool.